# Redirect all to a file using mod-rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all to `http://site.com/folder1/folder2/file.php`

works perfectly in Windows but not Linux

`.htaccess is inside folder1`

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder2/file.php
```

If I try to access http://site.com/folder1 without last "/" I get "Bad Request" error on Linux

**I do not want to change the URL in the address bar**

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If this is for an Apache httpd.conf, try using something like:

DocumentRoot "location folder1/folder1"

Comment: You said "If I try to access http://site.com/folder1 without last "/" I get "Bad Request" error on Linux".  Does that mean if you use the final "/" everything works on Linux, or does that err as well?

Comment: with "/" works great in Linux and Windows. Windows automatically put a "/" at the end.

Comment: OK.  What is in the rewrite logs?  (If you don't have one, set it up by putting RewriteLog "location/filename" under the RewriteEngine directive.)  Also, when you put the failed URL in the browser, does it change?  (You can see if it's redirecting to a bad location or just not redirecting at all.)